# Pydantic does not validate as expected in a simple model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I am first time learning pydantic, using this example. But I don't get any exception message as I expect, and the class has been made. What's the problem here?
I am using pedantic 0.18.2 on python 3.8.10 in a notebook in VScode environment:

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

# Now defining the Person class
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    is_married: bool

data ={
    'name': 32,
    'age': True,
    'is_married': 'hhh'
}
```

Now the try and exception block:

```
try:
    # Now to parse the data and validate it
    person = Person(**data)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

Now output. Looking into person:

```
person
```

It shows this result:

```
<Person name='32' age=1 is_married=False>
```

What should I fix here? How to prevent automatic change of data types?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Because models try to *coerce*. For that reason, if you want strict *validation* don't use `str` and `bool` since *pretty much any object can be coerced to one of those*. Use `pydantic.StrictString` and `pydantic.StrictBool`

Comment: So, if you look at the first Note in the [Model docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/), you see it states "pydantic is primarily a parsing library, not a validation library. Validation is a means to an end: building a model which conforms to the types and constraints provided. ... In other words, pydantic guarantees the types and constraints of the output model, not the input data."

Comment: Check out the interesting discussion here: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/578 Just know you aren't the only person that had a different impression of what to expect.

Comment: If your use-case is mere, strict runtime type checking, there are other projects that align with that (although, it may be worth sticking with Pydnatic because you can probably still accomplish what you want and it's a wildly succesfull and popular library). Check out: https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Every comment was very helpful.